# Not able to read validation messages from messages.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I'm creating a simple Spring REST application and following is my spring configuration class;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.example.spring" )
public class AppConfig {    
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }   
}
```

And this is what i have done in my controller class;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeModel employeeModel, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Errors: " + result.getAllErrors());
            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("status", "failure");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        employeeService.createEmployee(employeeModel);
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status", "success");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I have annotated my name field in EmployeeModel as below;

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

And this is my messages.properties file which is in the src/main/resources folder.

```
NotEmpty.employeeModel.name = Employee name is required.
```

But i'm not able to read this error message i'm getting only the default message for @NotEmpty.

I even tried with the following configuration;

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Kindly help me with this!

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I have the exact same problem and none of the suggestions below fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, maybe a little late, but this definitely worked for me.

Try to change your **`MessageSource`** config for this one:

```java
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    return messageSource;
}
```

And your **`LocalValidatorFactoryBean`** should be the same as you've already defined it.

```java
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

I tested using `Spring 5.0.1.Final` and `Hibernate Validator 5.4.2.Final` versions.

Comment: This does not work. If you have it running somehow can you share the entire code somewhere like github?

Comment: This works, you might want to inspect the configuration in this [working project](https://github.com/Jose-Rdz/spingere/tree/master/spingere). Before casting a negative vote perhaps you should make an effort on testing and sharing your results and not to expect others to try for you.

Comment: I did. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499891/spring-boot-mapping-validation-codes-to-messagesource-message) and [Here](https://github.com/JahnelGroup/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-validation). I came to conclusion that this only applies to Spring MVC (just like your example). This does NOT apply for regular Json payload's (i.e., REST API). In order to make that I work I had to write my own code, see [here](https://github.com/JahnelGroup/jts-auction/tree/3-validations/src/main/java/com/jahnelgroup/auctionapp/exception/message).

Comment: Well if I'm getting your point from _regular JSON payloads_... you can find a working validation example for JSON payloads [here](https://github.com/Jose-Rdz/spingere/blob/master/spingere/src/main/java/com/spingere/controller/UsuariosController.java) on methods using `@RequestBody`... there's no such difference about Spring MVC and REST API... btw if you consider your code the right approach maybe you could post your answer so others can benefit from it...

Comment: This helped me! I experienced issue reported in the question after upgrading spring (and sprig security) from 3 to 5 and hibernate from 5 to 6 and much more minor upgrades.... messages from properties file started not being found and not being displayed (before the upgrade it worked) THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Might help if still open.
Bumped on this for a similar case where i solved it by using the Interpolator explicitly:

```
 <!-- Messagesource for locales -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <util:list>
                <value>classpath:locales/messages/validation</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="resourceBundleMessageInterpolator"
          class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="messageSource"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="resourceBundleMessageInterpolator"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

**as opposite to** what also suggested in other threads given the supposed automatic injection via:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

With the above i managed to use placeholders in the validation property files by using brackets as well: i.e.:

```
@NotNull(message = "{message.notnull}")
```

Also the following threads hints were a must to me:

[Why Spring Message Interpolation Argument Replacement using Hibernate Validator don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416136/why-spring-message-interpolation-argument-replacement-using-hibernate-validator)
[How to use annotation validation in Spring with error message gotten from properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786582/how-to-use-annotation-validation-in-spring-with-error-message-gotten-from-proper)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `validator` to use your `messageSource`.

```
@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator validator() {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

And specify the message key on your model:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.employeeModel.name}")
private String name;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for MessageSource bean also.

Comment: @karthi I've used your code for messageSource bean definition.

Comment: @karthi hmm, try to use `factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());` instead of injection as a method param. I've modified the answer to reflect this way.

Comment: Do we need to use the Validator bean anywhere else as discussed here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225023/messageinterpolator-in-spring#11226683)

Comment: Now it's giving me the message key as the error message. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

old question, but this worked for me:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(final MessageSource messageSource) {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing everything right, applying all the fixes mentioned on 
Stack Overflow and spending hours just to get it to work, I was finally able to fix it by adding below on my messages.properties file

**`"# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file"`**

Note I am using intellij and for some weird reason it was not reading my messages.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html
we need to disassociate the bundle folder from intellij.
follow this your issue will be resolved.